# missing tracking id (&id) parameter in google analytics v3 for android app

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm newcomer in Google Analytics. I have a problem when I initialize a tracker. I want to initialize a tracker using `EasyTracker.getInstance(this);` in `onCreate()` method but when I run it and access the menu that already set the tracker, I've got warn message in logcat, that is `"missing tracking id (&id) parameter."`. But if I use `GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker("UA-xxxxxxxx-y");` to initialize the tracker, the message doesn't appear. I've set `EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);` in `onStart()` method and `EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);` in `onStop()` method.

This is my analytics.xml. Btw, I've already set the id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- The comicjp app Analytics Tracking Id -->
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-xxxxxxxx-y</string>

<!-- Enable automatic activity tracking -->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

<!-- Enable automatic exception tracking -->
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtException">true</bool>

<!-- Set the log level to verbose -->
<string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>

<!-- The interval of time after all the collected data
should be sent to the server, in seconds -->
<integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">30</integer>

<!-- The screen name that will appear in reports -->
<string name="com.example.gaaplication.MainActivity">MainActivity</string>
```

Why the warn message always appear if I'm using `EasyTracker.getInstance(this);`? How to use `EasyTracker.getInstance(this);` properly?

Comment: you can check my answer and some time Google tracking will taking time to display event on site in real time it will display device once you successfully configure

Answer (score 3):

In v4 I was getting `GAv4: Discarding hit. Missing tracking id parameter` because instead of:

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
```

I've added

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).newTracker(R.string.ga_trackingId);
```

Note the difference **xml.app_tracker** vs **string.ga_trackingId**!

Use `xml.app_tracker` configuration file!

Answer (score 1):

you need to set Own id here

```
<!-- The comicjp app Analytics Tracking Id -->
<string name="ga_trackingId">place your tracking id here</string>
```

Comment: Md Abdul Gafur, I already set it. It doesn't works. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Also java code option to set tracking id , please check Google document and sample code.

Answer (score 1):

For google analytics you need to register you application here [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) as all mobile application then it wil gives you ga_trackingId id

Now make one analytics.xml fine values folder in analytics file put below content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

 <!-- Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID -->
 <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-X</string>

<!-- Enable automatic activity tracking -->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

<!-- Enable automatic exception tracking -->
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

<string name="ga_appName">Location Serivce</string>
<string name="ga_appVersion">1.1.2</string>

<bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>

<item name="ga_dispatchPeriod" format="integer" type="integer">120</item>

<string name="ga_sampleFrequency">90</string>

<bool name="ga_anonymizeIp">true</bool>
<bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>

<string name="com.example.HomeActivity">HomeActivity</string>
<string name="com.example.SettingActivity">SettingActivity</string>
```

Now in home activity put below code for activity display

```
private Tracker tracker;
private String TAG_Tracker="HomeActivity";

MyApp.getGaTracker().set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, TAG_Tracker);
tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker(MyApp.GA_PROPERTY_ID);
HashMap<String, String> hitParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
hitParameters.put(Fields.HIT_TYPE, "ActivityView");
hitParameters.put(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, TAG_Tracker);
tracker.send(hitParameters);

//for button click and other event fire you need to put below code:

 public void onClick(View v) {
    tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("UI", "OnClick", "btnAdd", null).build());
}
```

Now MyApp.java

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

private static GoogleAnalytics mGa;
private static Tracker mTracker;

/*
 * Google Analytics configuration values.
 */
// Placeholder property ID.
public static final String GA_PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXXXXXX-X";

// Dispatch period in seconds.
private static final int GA_DISPATCH_PERIOD = 30;

// Prevent hits from being sent to reports, i.e. during testing.
private static final boolean GA_IS_DRY_RUN = false;

// GA Logger verbosity.
private static final LogLevel GA_LOG_VERBOSITY = LogLevel.INFO;

// Key used to store a user's tracking preferences in SharedPreferences.
private static final String TRACKING_PREF_KEY = "trackingPreference";

/*
 * Method to handle basic Google Analytics initialization. This call will
 * not block as all Google Analytics work occurs off the main thread.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void initializeGa() {
    mGa = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    mTracker = mGa.getTracker(GA_PROPERTY_ID);

    // Set dispatch period.
    GAServiceManager.getInstance().setLocalDispatchPeriod(GA_DISPATCH_PERIOD);

    // Set dryRun flag.
    mGa.setDryRun(GA_IS_DRY_RUN);

    // Set Logger verbosity.
    mGa.getLogger().setLogLevel(GA_LOG_VERBOSITY);

    // Set the opt out flag when user updates a tracking preference.
    SharedPreferences userPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    userPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                    String key) {
                if (key.equals(TRACKING_PREF_KEY)) {
                    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setAppOptOut(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false));
                }
            }
        });
    }

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    initializeGa();
}

/*
 * Returns the Google Analytics tracker.
 */
public static Tracker getGaTracker() {
    return mTracker;
}

/*
 * Returns the Google Analytics instance.
 */
public static GoogleAnalytics getGaInstance() {
    return mGa;
}
```

}

you need to define this myApp.java file in manifiest file like

```
 <application
    android:name="com.example.MyApp"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's work if I used Google Analytics property (GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker(MyApp.GA_PROPERTY_ID);), but I want to use EasyTracker property (EasyTracker.getInstance(this);).

Comment: sorry i dont know about EasyTracker till yet i had used on above way only so

Comment: Sorry PankajAndroid, that's my fault. I create xml folder in res folder to put analytics.xml. I can using EasyTracker property when I put analytics.xml in values folder. But, I still confused why Google Analytics message can appear in logcat if I didn't put analytics.xml in values folder. Can you explain it?

Comment: i cannot explaing it but from analytics it cannot find id and ga_sampleFrequency, id and all other thing thats why it cannot display

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, very strange, but i only solved by seeing the source code of the EasyTracker class. It fetches the is like this, using the resource name:

```
  String s = mParameterFetcher.getString("ga_trackingId");
```

AND if If you're using Android Maven plugin with package renaming, it will mess up (read this later: http://www.piwai.info/renaming-android-manifest-package/)...So in order to fix it, you have to READ the link + call the method **EasyTracker.setResourcePackageName()**

```
   // ensures that EasyTracker uses the overrider package.
    String appPackageName =  getPackageNameAccordingToWhatIsWrittenInThatBlogPost();
    //      Log.i(TAG, "loading appPackageName: " + appPackageName);
    EasyTracker.setResourcePackageName(appPackageName);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For google analytics v4, you should add global_tracker.xml. I think Google missing it in their Github repo.

1. Create res/xml
2. Create global_tracker.xml in res/xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="TypographyDashes"
>
  <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>
    <string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>
    <string name="ga_dryrun">true</string>

    <!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->

    <!--  The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-xxxxxxx-1</string>
</resources>
```